# Limite máximo de POST

Tags: php, html5

Estou tentando fazer um form de upload de video porém estou com um problema que impossibilita o upload pois sempre recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: POST Content-Length of 69509336 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0
```

Mesmo alterando o php.ini para que o posts não tenham limites

```
post_max_size=0
```

Oque posso fazer para resolver esse problema?

```
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>

        <?php

            $randomNum=substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstvwxyz"), 0, 11);
            $randomNum64 = base64_encode($randomNum);
            $base64 = base64_encode($randomNum);



           if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
               $errors= array();
               $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
               $file_size =$_FILES['file']['size'];
               $file_tmp =$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
               $file_type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
               $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['image']['name'])));


               if(empty($errors)==true){
                   move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
                   echo "Success";
               }else{
                   print_r($errors);
               }
           }

        ?>
```

Comment: Isso é uma limitação de servidor, se for a php.ini e pesquisar por post_max_size pode verificar qual o tamanho limite que tem para passar dados através de POST.

Comment: Estou utilizando o servidor local XAMPP, o código que coloquei do PHP ini foi o que eu coloquei em meu arquivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é uma boa prática deixar ilimitado, principalmente se for aberto, maaaaas...
Tente isto:

```
  post_max_size = 2M para
  post_max_size 100M
  upload_max_filesize = 8M para
  upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Comment: Sei que não é uma boa prática, porém coloquei para testar já que nenhuma opção estava funcionando. Atualizei os dados para os que você forneceu e continuo recebendo o mesmo erro

Comment: eu passei por isso essa semana e tive que alterar ambas variáveis, não se esqueça também de reiniciar o servidor do php para ter efeito. Faça um phpinfo(), sei que ja fez para verificar a alteração.

Comment: Reinicei e agora funcionou, muito obrigado :D

Comment: tive o mesmo problema com upload de videos tmb, passei o dia ralando por nao reiniciar o danado ... rs, vivendo, aprendendo e compartilhando.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é uma limitação de servidor, se for a php.ini e pesquisar por post_max_size pode verificar qual o tamanho limite que tem para passar dados através de POST.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode acessar essas informações via navegador.

Crie um arquivo php publique e acesse ele

```
 <?php

   phpinfo(); 

 ?>
```

Feita a devida alteração, reinicie o servidor para que tenha efeito.

> uma dica que poderá ser útil: `Em alguns casos, você precisará aumentar o tempo máximo de execução.`

Comment: Eu já alterei essa opção em meu php ini

Comment: @LuhanSalimena, eu nunca mexi no php.ini mas parece que tem que reiniciar o servidor para que a alteração tenha efeito, Fez isso?

Comment: O amigo ali de cima me auxilou nisso, eu não tinha reiniciado o servidor por isso a alteração não estava surtindo efeito

Comment: @LuhanSalimena o amigo lá de cima andou colando, minha resposta é mais antiga hahaha :) além do meu comentário que é mais antigo ainda

Comment: @LuhanSalimena, de qualquer forma vai uma dica que poderá ser útil algum dia. `Em alguns casos, você precisará aumentar o tempo máximo de execução.`